# Perl error when running cron through command line?

Tags: perl

I recently moved my website to a new server and it appears to have issues running my Perl cron jobs.

```
root@server [/]# perl /home/username/backend/cron/daily_first.pl

Can't locate Proc/PID/File.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/username/backend/cron/../lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /home/username/backend/cron/cronjob.pl line 8.
```

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/username/backend/cron/cronjob.pl line 8.

Here's a copy of the first 9 lines of code in the file I'm running:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw/$Bin/;
use lib "$Bin/../lib";

use Proc::PID::File;
exit if Proc::PID::File->running( { dir => $Bin } );
```

In case it helps, all my Perl cron jobs appear to be giving errors like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had a more modern version of `perl` you would get the slightly more helpful error message:

> Can't locate Proc/PID/File.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Proc::PID::File module) (@INC contains:

You don't have [the `Proc::PID::File` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::PID::File) installed, or your `@INC` path is misconfigured (so it doesn't include the directory where you have it installed).

Install the module using whatever method your favour (I lean towards [the `cpanm` tool](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) ([install instructions](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Installing-to-system-perl)).